# Consolidate Batch of ETH Wallets w/ERC20 Tokens?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, private-key, import, batch

I have a large number of Ethereum wallets with small amounts of ERC-20 tokens in each.  How can I send all of these tokens to a single ethereum wallet without doing this process manually? (it would take a long time)

Comment: Is this a recurring situation or a one-time effort? Does "large" mean hundreds or thousands?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do that manually. Even if you create a script, you are going to need to add manually all your private keys to be able to sign transfer transactions.

Comment: Why can't the script access the private keys?  I have a spreadsheet of private and public keys.

Comment: Since you already have the private keys, you can do a javascript script and use geth to do the job for you. You are going to need [ethereumjs-accounts](https://github.com/SilentCicero/ethereumjs-accounts)  and use `web3ethsendrawtransaction`[web3ethsendrawtransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction)

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that it might be faster to do it manually than trying to automate a process that you might only do once anyway.

Comment: Not sure how long it would take to automate this but it might be worth the investment if I can easily adapt it for use in the future.  Right now it would take about 30-40 hours of manual labor to do this.  I'm thinking of hiring someone to do this since each wallet has a small amount of funds and have them send the funds to a wallet that only I hold the private keys to. I could slowly release more private keys to them once it's confirmed that they sent the funds from the addresses as promised.  When developers air drop a token do they manually execute each transaction?